# Unable to load dynamic library when it goes to live shared hosting

Tags: codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

I got this error when i moved my project folder to live shared hosting.

How to resolve Plz ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like PHP MYSQL PDO module is missing. Please try changing the PHP version from cPanel. If the error still persists, you may have to run the EasyApache again and install the MySQL PDO module.